# In a WSDL file, via a free solution can the XPath of a response element be determined without invoking the service?

Tags: xml, xpath, open-source, soapui, xmlspy

In a WSDL file, can the XPath of a request/response element be determined without invoking the service? I mean just by openeing an WSDL and generating request + response messages.

Or do I need additional software, like the paid SOAPUI PRO tool which can do it as already [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512117/in-a-wsdl-file-can-the-xpath-of-a-response-element-be-determined-without-invoki)? (I really want to avoid paid and closed-surce helpers.)

Comment: WSDL is used to describe the web service, its input and output parameters. You cannot generate a request/response XPath from it. You need the request/response xml. I do not know if an independent library that will give you the request/response xmls from wsdl so you'll have to use soapUI/xmlspy or something similar. To access the value of an element you can use `//*:ELEMENT_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured out a workaround to get this done. Not a preferred way of working though, so better, more efficient answers are still welcome!

Workaround:

1. Create XML resuest+response messages for the operation, from the WSDL:
   a) Create a Mockup service with SOAPUI. That way SOAOPUI will create a dummy response message for you.
   b) The request message is already available by default
2. copy-paste the dummy message to some program that is capable of resolving the Xpath from an XML file (e.g. XMLSpy can resolve the XPath for an element via the grid-view, [other tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915219/tool-to-find-out-xpath) are available as well)